# List View smoothScrollToPosition is not scrolling to expected position

Tags: android, android-listview

I have List View. List Items are Web View. I want to scroll to particular position.
When I call mListview.smoothScrollToPosition(position) its not scrolling to that position.
It starts scrolling but it will stop in the middle. Its not scrolling to expected position.
All list items are Web View in my case. Is rendering of Web View is causing the problem?
Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To what position it scroll? pls put some code also

Comment: It seems you are loading the images in webView instead of ImageView. Try by replacing your webview with imageview, then you will come to know whether this is due to webview in your list.

Answer (score 0):

try using the following code to scroll to your specified position

```
...
mListview.setAdapter(adapter);
mListview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mListview.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    }
});
...
```

Comment: can u define the variable position ?
is it variable for listview or arraylist

Comment: The position variable is the integer value of your item in the list view.

Comment: we cannot use this position variable of list view. It keeps on changing

Comment: Once the adapter is created the list item and their respective don't change even if you add new item to the adapter. Think of an adapter as a queue, new items are added at the end so they don't disturb the position of other item. Unless & until you delete item from list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mListView.setSelection(position_scroll);
```